# gcc generic march for all the x64 platforms

Tags: gcc, 64-bit

GCC have `-march=` and `-mtune` option as described [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/i386-and-x86_002d64-Options.html). But it is not obvious which of the options to choose for **x64** platform as generic one. Say, `-mtune=` have the `generic` value, but `-march=` for **x64** have no.

I suspect that `-march=nocona` (as frequently seen everywhere) or even `-march=i686 -m64` is the solution, but I'm not sure.

Comment: You need to clarify what you want?  Are you compiling a 64-bit executable on a 32-bit system or do you intend your app only for 64-bit systems?

Comment: 64bit host and target (without loss of generality)

Comment: I want the program to starts up at all (from the ancient x64 to the modern corei7-avx) processors.

Comment: The default *is* generic. That is, simply don't pass any option.

Comment: @MarcGlisse: the default is whatever has been passed to the `configure` script when building GCC.

Comment: @Fanael: sounds like a case of "doctor, it hurts when I do that".

Comment: @MarcGlisse You are not right (see below).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The generic x86-64 `-march` is `-march=x86-64`.

It is *usually* the default for GCC targeting x86-64, but that default can be changed at `configure` time by passing appropriate value to `--with-arch`.

Comment: But `echo "" | gcc -v -E - 2>&1 | grep cc1` produce the following:
`c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/cc1.exe -E -quiet -v -iprefix c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/ -D_REENTRANT - -mtune=core2 -march=nocona`

Comment: @Dukales: on my machine it produces `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.0/cc1 -E -quiet -v - -mtune=generic -march=x86-64`. See the point about `--with-arch`.

Comment: Thank you. So, it depends on the build of GCC/MinGW.

Comment: @Dukales that output shows only the optimizations used to build the GCC executables, in your case tuned to an Intel Core2 CPU and using everything up to SSE3.

Comment: @rubenvb: actually, no. It shows the arguments the driver passes to `cc1`.

Comment: Oh, then you've got a dangerous GCC build on your hands.

Comment: @rubenvb Ok, it is your rival - mingw-builds project =)

Comment: @Dukales lol yes. It's only dangerous because one would expect an executable compiled default options (no `-march`) to work on all CPUs. In this case it wouldn't. Be careful `:P`

Comment: Why it's not documented in `man gcc`, `-mtune=cpu-type` in the `cpu-type` list also used by `-march`? I took me some time to get this to work. If not for this answer here, I would still be reading why I got problems using the `i686` instead.

Comment: Is there a reason that GCC doesn't support the more common name `x86_64` instead of `x86-64`?