# What is the default for gcc -march option?

Tags: gcc, gcc4, gcc4.7

The gcc info file says in the section on x86-64 specific flags, among
other things:

```
There is no `-march=generic' option because `-march'
indicates the instruction set the compiler can use, and there
is no generic instruction set applicable to all processors.
In contrast, `-mtune' indicates the processor (or, in this
case, collection of processors) for which the code is
optimized.
```

My question then is, what instruction (sub-)set does gcc compile for
when no -march option is given?  There is a lot of related information
about -march and -mtune in the webosphere, but none that I could find
which answers this simple question.  It can't be march=native, or else
it would be impossible to compile generic distribution kernels and
binary packages.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Obtaining current GCC architecture](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11727855/obtaining-current-gcc-architecture)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The default flags for gcc can be set when gcc itself is compiled. Run:

```
  gcc -Q --help=target
```

to see what the default is on your machine. Likely it'll just be [x86-64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16273561/gcc-generic-march-for-all-the-x64-platforms)
 even though the man page doesn't document that as a value for -march-

Comment: Ok, the output contains march=x86-64.  But since it is undocumented as you noted, this really only shifts the question: what does it really mean in terms of the instructions?

Comment: It should be the base x86-64 instruction set, common to all x86-64 CPUs.

Comment: ... which is something the documetation says doesn't exist :-P

Comment: From what I can tell, the documenation says that in the context of 386 and x86-64 CPUs, which is true, there's no common instruction sets among those. But for x86-64 CPUs, there is.

Comment: For anyone who cares, the x86-64 option was added to the documentation https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Options.html